# AntDesign TimePicker React component is not rendering as a dropdown

Tags: reactjs, antd

Just experimenting with antd's React based UI kit, however it seems that some of the input components not rendering as they should, ex. as a dropdown.

Please see below a random component and how it's being rendered (I added 2 components within mine, TimePicker and DatePicker to demonstrate this)

Looking through the docs I understood that these input or form components must be wrapped within < Form > and < Form.Item >, I tried with and without these.

I also tried both with and without providing default props, still nothing, the documentation doesn't mention these as mandatory ones.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form>
            <Form.Item>
                <TimePicker/>
                <DatePicker/>
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
}
```

actual: [actual render][1]

expected: https://ant.design/components/time-picker

Thanks guys!

update: I created a new react app on my work mac using npx create-react-app (yesterday I used my personal windows) and had npm i antd. I made sure I have nothing in the new app which could cause issue, only the boilerplate, then I added a component exactly how it is in the ant design documentation.

I am still experiencing the same issue. Sure it's missing something fundamental within ant-design but it seems it's not in the documentation. Anyone who ever used the ant-design components with react, have you done anything specific apart from installing the package and importing the components before using?

It looks like it disregards the css.

Comment: Did you import the css styles of antd?

Comment: Yes,  and just double checked in node_modules, they're there, also the variables are not overwritten, I don't have any custom code for css for now, just trying to get the hang of the library

Comment: Shouldn't you wrap each one in a different `<Form.Item>` ?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference unfortunately, in fact, I only had the TimePicker, I added DatePicker as well only for the sake of this post.

Comment: update: I created a new react app on my work mac (yesterday I used my personal windows) and had npm i antd. I made sure I have nothing in the new app which could cause the confusion, only the boilerplate, then I added a module exactly how it is in the ant design documentation, finally I am experiencing the same issue. I am sure I am missing something fundamental with ant design but it seems it's not in the documentation. Anyone who ever used the ant design components with react, have you done anything specific apart from installing the package and importing the components before using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if anyone else is experiencing this, found the solution:

Antd's css was not applied because I forgot to import it to my App.css:

@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';

Simple mistake to make.

Solution was found in the below link:
https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import/issues/89

mthrsj also asked about this, I overlooked it when I checked.

Comment: You could import it from your `App.css` or you could import it even from `App.js`. By the way, happy for you find out what was wrong.